PyQt5 Crashes when I open a folder which contains files with .json or .js extension in QTreeView
I work in VSCode on Ubuntu LTS 24.04.
I use PyQt5.
I have the following folders with files in the root path of my project:

I use the following code:
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QFileSystemModel


DATA_PATH = Path('data')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    
        uic.loadUi('windows/basic.ui', self)
        self.tree_view = self.findChild(QTreeView, 'treeView')
        model = QFileSystemModel(self)

        model.setRootPath(str(DATA_PATH))
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        self.tree_view.setRootIndex(model.index(str(DATA_PATH)))

        self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()

Here is the basic.ui file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>497</width>
    <height>372</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <widget class="QTreeView" name="treeView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>461</width>
      <height>291</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>497</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFiles">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Files</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action_Create_File"/>
    <addaction name="actionLoad_File"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="action_Import_File"/>
    <addaction name="action_Export_File"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFiles"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionOpen_file">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open file</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionOpen_recent">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open recent</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_Create_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>&amp;New File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_Import_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>&amp;Import File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_Export_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>&amp;Export File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionLoad_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Load File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


Now when I try to expand the folder "2024" with all the JSON files in it, the program crashes.
But when I expand the folder "2025" with the python and text file in it, it works fine.
I also tried to expand the folder when a file with the Javascript file extension is in it, that also crashes.
I tried to change the extension from .json to .jso and that works.
I tried to open a folder outside of my project same behavior as in my project folder.
I expect the QTreeView to expand the folders no matter which file it contains.
On the image you can see my desired behavior:

The folder 2025 expands but the when I try to expand the 2024 folder the program crashes.
I start the program via inntegrated terminal in VSCode python __main__.py.
There are no debug logs from PyQt5 when QT debug env: export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
The Program just stops responding like in the following image to see:
Visual Studio Code is not responing
Edit
The Programm works just fine when executed outside of VSCode.

Have you tested the code outside of VSCode in a standard console? Because I cannot reproduce any of the behaviour you describe when I do that. This would suggest the problem lies with VSCode (or one of its extensions, such as a debugger), rather than with Qt5.

@ekhumoro The problem is indeed in vscode, as the OP confirmed (see the Staging Ground comments).

Unfortunately somebody irresponsibility approved your post before you could update it as I asked. Please do [edit] your post to clarify that the problem does not happen outside VS Code, and include the specific VS code version, its configuration, etc.. Also consider running VSC from the terminal and check possible output for that too.

@musicamante Before your comment, I had no idea what the Staging Ground was. Even now after reading about it, I have no idea how to view its comments, since there's no obvious link associated with the public question.

@ekhumoro It's here. It's normally accessible from the post history.

@musicamante Ah, I hadn't realised a timeline link has now been added to all questions and answers by default. This used to require a stack-app/user-script, but it kept breaking, so I stopped using it.

How much space does 2024 folder take up?

just a few Kilobytes.
The size is not the Problem, it has to do something with the file formats.
VSCode just breaks, when I open a folder with files, which have a certain file extension, in the treeview widget but via an external terminal it works just fine.
